# Set an homepage and create a link to redirect to an other project with Jekyll/Github pages

Tags: redirect, jekyll

I must have missed the informations but I don't know how do two things with jekyll and Github pages...

**First question:**

With the minima theme, my homepage is the `index.md` with the layout default :

```
---
layout: default
title: Homepage
---
```

I didn't changed the `default.html`. The content of my `index.md` is well displayed as my homepage, but a new tab was created in the navigation bar with the title " Homepage "... There is a way to display my homepage without created a new tab in the navigation bar ?

**Second question :**

I create a file `resume.md` to create a new tab in the navigation bar with " resume " as title :

```
---
layout: default
title: Resume
---
```

A resume tab was created. But I would like that when I click on it, this tab redirect me to my other project Github pages which is my resume. 
I don't know how to do that...

Can you help me with these to problems ?

Answer (score 0):

**Find the solution to my first problem :**

In the `_config.yml` file, uncomment the #header_pages. That allow to change the order of the navigation ( an other problem that I have... ) and not display the homepage tab in the navigation bar.

Still the second problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding question two:**

You could try using Jekyll plugin `jekyll-redirect-from` [1] to create a page on your website to redirect to another URL [2].

> Sometimes, you may want to redirect a site page to a totally different
>   website. This plugin also supports that with the redirect_to key:
>
> `title: My amazing post`
>
> `redirect_to: http://www.github.com`

[1] https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from

[2] https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from#redirect-to

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same sceneraio before. Specifically, I have my personal home page setup on github. Meanwhile, I aslo have two seperate projects hosted at two differnt urls, which I want to show them as hyperlinked navigation tabs on my homepage as well.

The solution I  used is to cutomize the navigation tab setion in the default.html as below :

```
   <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/projects">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://projection1.example.com/" target="_blank">MyProject1</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://projection2.example.com/" target="_blank">MyProject2</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
```

you can replace the url above with your own external link.
Setting target="_blank" will open the link in a new page when you click on the hyperlinked tab (i.e. MyProject1 or MyProject2).

FYI, here is my account:https://trencyclopedia.github.io/